# Java JTabbedPane, how can I select a tab from a button?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

How can I select a tab as if it was clicked by clicking on a button?
I have googled and looked at all the actions but there are just just so many... :(

Anyone know off hand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add an action listener to the button that calls setSelectedComponent, or setSelectedIndex on the JTabbedPane.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean about the button, but you might be looking for [`setSelectedComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedComponent(java.awt.Component)) or [`setSelectedIndex`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex(int)).

Answer (score 1):

If your jtabbedpane's name is mytabbedpane it goes like this:

```
mytabbedpane.getSelectedIndex();
```

which returns the int of that tab (0,1 .. n) or

```
mytabbedpane.getSelectedComponent();
```

which returns the String of the tab's name ("Firts tab","Second tab",...).

If you want to use the "getSelectedComponent()" for boolean logic you should write something like:

```
if (mytabbedpane.getSelectedComponent().equals("First tab")) {
     //code here
}
```

and for the "getSelectedIndex()" one is of course:

```
if (mytabbedpane.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
     //code here
}
```

Comment: .getSelectedComponent() returns Component, not String.

Answer (score 1):

Double click on button, put the follwing code

```
JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(1);
```

Tabs starts from 0 to N left to right order

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
tabbedPane.addTab(tabName, component);
int count = tabbedPane.getTabCount();
tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(count-1);
```